# How do I detect #regform on the end of a url?

Tags: php

I am having trouble figuring out how to detect the #regform at the end of a url and when I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] they don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean text after a hashmark, it is called the *hash* of a link, and does not get sent to the server. You can get it in javascript with `location.hash`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not detect fragment part of URL because it is not sent to server it is used client side by browser.

Hence you can not get it using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP, you can't get the #Hash value, because it's not passed to the server.

You have to get the value client side using JavaScript.